# Is it possible to add SQL alias from subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to add aliases to sql query from select subquery.

something like

```
SELECT 
     ID AS(
            SELECT 
                 TOP1 NAME 
            FROM MYTABLE
     )
     ,NAME
     ,SURNAME 
FROM PEOPLE
```

Is it possible?

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '('. Msg 102,
>   Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 156, Level
>   15, State 1, Line 8 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'

Comment: Which DB are you using? When you tried that query, what happened?

Comment: Switch order, `(SELECT TOP1 NAME FROM MYTABLE) AS ID`. Doesn't make much sense though. Either have a correlated sub-query, or do a join.

Comment: @jarlh, you didn't get, he wants dynamic alias

Comment: Yes - I'm looking for dynamic alias, it is not backwards. What for? I have headlines for result in different table.

Comment: @Kelk, it is possible with dynamic statement.

Comment: @Alfabravo here is result:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only possible with this:

```
DECLARE @n VARCHAR(MAX), @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT TOP 1 @n = NAME FROM MYTABLE
SET @sql = 'SELECT ID AS ' + @n + ', NAME, SURNAME FROM PEOPLE'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: I guess `TOP 1` is not needed.

Comment: @Prdp, yes has no sense without ordering